# Order or Sort Column Items In A Specific Order Use Snowflake Code

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake.  I have a working code that generates what the results, but I would like the items within a specific column to sort in a specific manner:
Desired sort within column - Nat > Reg > Air > Dip  >Dive

Below is a snip from the Snowflake code:

```
A.LEVEL = B.LEVEL 
and A.NAME = B.NAME
and A.TYPE = B.TYPE

ORDER BY Case
When Level = 'Nat' Then 1
When Level = 'Reg' Then 2
When Level = 'Air' Then 3
When Level = 'Dip' Then 4
When Level = 'Dive' Then 5
END, Name ASC
```

The result come out all over the place and in no particular order.

Any thoughts on what to try or do?

Comment: Are you sure the literals  correct and for instance do not contain invisible characters? What is the output of `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE Level = 'Nat'`?

Comment: The output begins with 'DMA' and there is no order after that.  No invisible characters.

Comment: Make sure your CASE statement contains values that are of the same case as the values in your table.

Answer (score 0):

The snippet does not contain full code, but there are two things that could be done:

1. Use qualified name
2. Use case insensitive comparison

Query:

```
-- ...
A.LEVEL = B.LEVEL 
and A.NAME = B.NAME
and A.TYPE = B.TYPE

ORDER BY CASE
         When A.LEVEL ILIKE 'Nat' Then 1
         When A.LEVEL ILIKE 'Reg' Then 2
         When A.LEVEL ILIKE 'Air' Then 3
         When A.LEVEL ILIKE 'Dip' Then 4
         When A.LEVEL ILIKE 'Dive' Then 5
         END, Name ASC
```